# Excel if 2 rows are similar, delete the second one

Tags: excel, phpexcel, libreoffice

I have a sheet with generated dates, for example : 
[image: Worksheet]

This cells are generated by my software. There are 2 calculations : of bank vs the analyst.
In this 2 tables are included only charges that current loan has.

In already generated Excel as you can see attached, I want to write a formula that compare each Charge (Interest, Frais de garantie, etc) from first "table" with the same values from the second table. If values of this charges (6938.82, 236.75) are equal, then delete all row from the second table.
In the second table I want to remain only the charges that has the red value, I mean only the charges that has value 0 in first table.

I don't know how to do it in Excel, I'm a PHP developer and have somehow to solve current issue.
I see it kind of :  
If text-cell from column A has a match in same column, compare their values from column B. If values are equal, delete entire row from the second table, else -> do nothing.

To generate the Excel I am using PHPExcel.

Comment: You need `vba` code to delete.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Office it would be easy with VBA, but in LibreOffice you can't use the Microsoft script language. You may be able to do it with Libre-Office Basic. Which don't have really good documentation or examples.

But when you already generate a excel file from your program, why don't you handle this in the generating program? It is easy to ready and manipulate excel files from C#/Java/Python etc. I never tried this in PHP, but it should be possible to.

See this GitHub Project:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Yep, I know and I'm working with this library, I already achieve this "functional" with it, but there is a huge problem that this module is running very slow. Some simple excel manipulations cause waiting for 10-30 second of generating to download file. That's why I tried to achieve on-open with Excel function.

Comment: so better calculate the result in php before writting anything to excel and check what you really want to write to the excel file with your modul. As more you can handle in your PHP script before going to write it to the excel file, the faster your application will be :)